# Materialcss modal not working with datatables.js

Tags: datatables, material-design

I am trying to build an admin dashboard using material design framework. As a part of it, I am trying to add `modal-trigger` element inside a `<td></td>` tag of a table that uses datatable.js library. But when I click on the trigger no modal is appearing. Did anyone face similar issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what's happening is that your `trigger` isn't in the DOM when you draw the table, but without seeing your code I can't be sure. Generally, it will trigger a modal when it is clicked or something? You might want to change the actual triggering to clicking on a td with a given class contained within the table so something like this:

```
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(){//Open Modal});
```

This would work on the first page but not after the first draw of the table as the event had been registered before the elements were within the DOM. Rather, you'd need to listen to the click within the table like this:

```
$("#table-id").on("click", ".modal-trigger", function(){//Open Modal});
```

I hope that makes sense and that it helps, if not perhaps work up a JSFiddle illustrating your issue?